# Nested controller vs directive in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, controller, nested, directive

Could any angularjs guru please tell me when is it better to use nested controller and when to use directive.

Up until now, I've used mostly directive and cannot think of a scenario where I would chose to write a child controller.

Comment: I used to use nested controllers at the beginning, when I had not grasped the meaning of the directives. Not any more - now I tend to use the controller only for the routes and directives for everything else. This is not a proper answer, just a comment saying "I agree with your opinion: use directives".

Comment: I have the same experience. First with nested controllers and then move them to directives.

Answer (score -1):

My take:

Use:

- **Controllers** (nested) for hierarchical relationships, parts of a page with different purposes are typically child controllers of the page controller.
- **Directives** for stand-alone components that can be reused anywhere/in multiple places. Especially when DOM manipulation is involved, a directive is the right choice. Example: a custom drop down control.
- **Services** for sharing data between controllers that are not nested (no parent/child inheritance).

Comment: I think you have a valid point, treating directives as something independent. I guess nested controller can be used to separated different concern on a page. But personally unless the controller get really messy. I would rather merge it to the parent controller. I used to have nested controller so I can share it with other controllers but then convert them to directive seem to make it simpler. But you answer has brought up a great case for nested controller I think. If you have one page app. with lots of interaction then it make sense to separate the concerns